# Decreasing the length of array based on percentage of max value in same array

Tags: python, python-2.7, function

I am trying to figureout the problem with the code since couple of days now but no luck. I am decreasing the length of array based on some percent of max value in same array but getting some error with the type of values. I have also followed other post but unable to fix this error of function and float. Can someone please guide me where I am doing wrong here? First small function is giving me the maximum element in the array multiplied by some value of percent as given below:

```
p = [23, 45.3, 10, 7.56, 5]
percent = 0.15

def max_p(p,percent):
  max_val = max(p) * percent
  return max_val
```

and then I am calling the value from the above function to his function as given below:

```
n_array = [3,2,1,4,5,7]
Olen = len(p)

def rmv(p, n_array,percent):
    max_val = max_p(p,percent)
    for i in p:
        if i < (max_val):
            p.remove(i)
    Nlen = len(p)
    kunfu = Olen - Nlen
    tr_new = n_array[: len(n_array) - kunfu]
    return tr_new
```

when I run everything it throws me the error

```
max_val = max(p) * percent
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'function' and 'float'
```

I have tried using str and float to align max(p) and percent to compatible format but still it gives error of type: function and float or str and int etc. I am calling the function in this manner

```
p = [23, 45.3, 10, 7.56, 5]
n_array = [3,2,1,4,5,7]
percent = 0.15
ans = rmv(p, n_array,percent)
print ans
```

Comment: please, add the code where you call that function

Comment: @BohdanKaminskyi that code is given above in second part see the function rmv please. I am calling in 2nd line of rmv function.

Comment: from the code you posted, i cannot find the actual call of rmv function

Comment: @BohdanKaminskyi I have edited the description for you. Please look for the call of rmv (which has the max_p call inside it) in the last part of the description.

Answer (score 0):

Running the code as, not giving any errors:

```
def rmv(p, n_array,percent):
    max_val = max_p(p,percent)
    for i in p:
        if i < (max_val):
            p.remove(i)
    Nlen = len(p)
    kunfu = Olen - Nlen
    tr_new = n_array[: len(n_array) - kunfu]
    return tr_new

def max_p(p,percent):
    max_val = max(p) * percent
    return max_val

p = [23, 45.3, 10, 7.56, 5]
Olen = len(p)
n_array = [3,2,1,4,5,7]
percent = 0.15
ans = rmv(p, n_array,percent)

print(ans)
```

Comment: When i run this on seperately as file it works but when i use these with other functions in a package it throws an error.